# What does the black arrow under the bin GUI icon represent?

Tags: gui, symbolic-link

Today I noticed that most bin/"executables" don't have the black arrow right of the bottom-of-the-logo-diamond, but a few do. From the ones i've seen, I think they're programs that are currently running.

Is this the case or is it something else?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. They are Link to Executables. In fact, they are symbolic links.

[image]

Comment: so they are programs that are also symbolic links?